# Print out df command's output using grep in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script where I need to print out the content of `Available` in `/home`. So in the below example, it would be `458G`. I was thinking maybe I can use `grep` or `awk` and then `print $3` or something like that? I'd appreciate the help here! I'm new to bash script.

```
**Filesystem          1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on**

/dev/mapper/cl-root       50G   28G       23G  55% /
devtmpfs                  48G    0G       48G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     48G    1G       48G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     48G    1G       47G   1% /run
tmpfs                     48G    0G       48G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                  1G    1G        1G  45% /boot
/dev/sda1                  1G    1G        1G   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/cl-home      492G   34G      458G   7% /home
tmpfs                     10G    1G       10G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `/home` as an argument to `df`.

```
df /home
```

Answer (score 0):

`df -h | grep /home | awk '{print $4}'` will give you `Available` field for `/home`

Comment: I suggest `df -hP /home | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with `bash`. Since it has a `linux` tag, then simply:

```
df -h --output=avail /home | tail -n1
```